# How show variable from controller to html page(AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I create controller and html page.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.view3', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view3', {
            templateUrl: 'view3/view3.html',
            controller: 'View3Ctrl'
        });
    }])

    .controller('View3Ctrl', [function($scope) {
        $scope.my_name = "Pasha";
    }]);
```

and it is my html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My view</title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Hello Pavel</p>
<div>{{my_name}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want show in browser my html.

```
Hello Pavel

Pasha

Angular seed app: v0.1
```

But I see in browser

```
 Hello Pavel
 {{my_name}}   
 Angular seed app: v0.1
```

I use example from [link](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp)

EDIT: I add appjs.

It is my app js file my file it is my file:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.view3',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

Comment: there is no controller named View3Ctrl in your html

Comment: what?????????????????????????????

Comment: I don't see this module `myApp.view3`? Do you really have it? Like `<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">`

Comment: I edit quation.............

Comment: <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp"> - not work

Comment: Please create a plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add ng-app and ng-controller to your body
2. Add '$scope' in the controller

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.view3', [])

    .controller('View3Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.my_name = "Pasha";
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My view</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp.view3" ng-controller="View3Ctrl">
<p> Hello Pavel</p>
<div>{{my_name}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why this answer is not worked for you @ user5620472? could you explain please?

Comment: It is worked but I think it incorect. I config views in app.js file and include to index.html. I think I not need Include <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script> to each html file or I wrong?

Comment: @user5620472 No need to include the script tag in each html file. This is was included to make the piece of sample script to work.

Comment: I was think if I include .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
            templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
            controller: 'View2Ctrl'
        });
    }])
I not need write controller name in html page and it mapped automaticly

Comment: You are right. View3Ctrl will be available in view3.html

Comment: But it not available

Comment: Provide your plunker url

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="View3Ctrl as ctrl">{{ ctrl.my_name}}</div>
```

You also need to set your documents `ng-app` attribute. See more in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00).

Comment: It is not work! browser show - {{ctrl.my_name}}(<div ng-controller="View3Ctrl as ctrl">{{ctrl.my_name}}</div>)

Comment: have you set the ng-app?